# Почему изображение заголовка теряет качество?

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет. Проблема в том, что когда я вывожу изображение заголовка через `<?php header_image(); ?>`, оно теряет своё качество в отличии от того, что я вывожу из стока (через background, через css). Как это поправить?

Comment: header_image() формирует готовый html - скорее всего проблема в этом. Я бы проверил какую ссылку на изображение выводит get_header_image()

Comment: Без ссылки на сайт можно долго заниматься гаданием. Вангую несоответствие физ. размеров к выводимым.

Answer (score 0):

В файле `functions.php` я нашёл `THEME-NAME_custom_header_setup` и изменил параметр `'width'` на `'flex-width'` и его значение на `true`: `'flex-width'             => true`. После этого в самих настройках внешнего вида при добавлении изображения заголовки не будет работать кнопка "обрезать", но появится кнопка "не обрезать", которая сохранит исходные размеры.

Comment: Ответ без указания используемой вами темы не имеет никакой пользы для посетителей сайта. Вы в самом деле думаете, что во всех темах так, как у вас?